# Is fullscreen the same as kiosk mode in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have my web app running in kiosk mode (in the chrome browser) and on another machine I have the browser in full screen mode (i.e. via F11). I was wondering if running the apps this way is the same in terms of what happens under the hood and functionality provided?

The reason I ask is with the full screen mode I noticed every time a network request is made I see the loading notification status bar in the bottom left hand corner popup momentarily. I do not remember seeing that in kiosk mode. I wonder if this can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're referring to Single App Kiosk Mode.

When a chromebook is in single app kiosk mode, the ONLY application that may launch is the chosen kiosk application. The app will automatically open in fullscreen mode when the device is booted up, and in most cases cannot be exited.

The reason that loading bars and other features are disabled in kiosk mode is that the device is only designed to serve one purpose - to delver the application that is disabled.

There are several differences between functionality of non managed and managed devices when it comes to single app kiosk mode.

Here's a great reference: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Maumee for the reply. I should have been a bit more descriptive. I was referring to when you run chrome.exe and pass the flag -kiosk (so this applies in general and not to a chromebook). We launch a browser full screen/in kiosk mode on boot up on the hardware we sell.